# How can I see the size (in bytes) of a resource in a UIWebView using Safari 7 Web Inspector?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari, web-inspector

I'm working on reducing the size (in bytes) of images on an app that uses `UIWebview`s to display advertisements. On a normal webpage, I can refresh the page and the weight icon in Web Inspector will then list the size of resources.

But when I refresh my `UIWebView`, my content disappears, and so I can't see the weights panel.

Notes:

The content for the `UIWebView` is loaded by the `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`, which passes in the HTML string with a `baseURL` of `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not an ideal workaround, but my solution was to listen to the `UIWebView` delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. If the `navigationType` is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload` I simply called the `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method with the same string I used before. This enables the weight icon, taking me to the page listing the size of each resource.